# Word boundary issue in a dynamic C# regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to build a regex pattern with some parts of pattern retrieved from a database.

For example

```
string pt= "@\"\\b(" + db.GetPattern + ")\\b\"";        
Regex regex = new Regex(pt, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
return regex.Replace(input, "*");
```

Although I tried to escape it, I couldn't get it to work. If I build the pattern manually as

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b(test|test2)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
return regex.Replace(input, "*");
```

it works fine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try

```
string pt = @"\b(" + db.GetPattern + @")\b";
```

or alternatively:

```
string pt = string.Concat(@"\b(", db.GetPattern, @")\b");
```

The basic reason is that the pattern you give as an example and the string you are building are quite different. Things like literal strings, such as `@"foo"` only matter to the C# compiler, after compilation all strings are equal. The two strings `@"\b"` and `"\\b"` are completely equal, the only difference is in how the C# compiler evaluates escape characters inside it. Which means that there is absolutely no need to incorporate C# syntax into strings you use at runtime.

Basically the string you created contained:

```
@"\b(test|test2)\b"
```

whereas you wanted the pattern

```
\b(test|test2)\b
```

So parts like the `@` sign and the quotation marks were literals for the regex. Thus it wouldn't match.